# simulate lapply / loop over a list of parameters

Tags: r, loops, nested, lapply

I would like to simulate the frequency and severity over a list of parameters.
Here is the case for the first item in the list:

```
data <- data.frame(
lamda = c(5, 2, 3),
meanlog = c(9, 10, 11), 
sdlog = c(2, 2.1, 2.2))

freq <- rpois(s, data$lamda[1])

freqsev <- lapply(freq, function(k) rlnorm(k, data$meanlog[1], sdlog = data$sdlog[1]))

freq
freqsev
```

How I set up a loop or an lapply statement to iterate over all the items in data? (not just the first).

Thanks.

Comment: Not reproducible. What is `s`?

Comment: Sorry I missed a line;  s <- 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map` (from the `purrr` package, part of the `tidyverse` package) as follows to create list columns. The contents are now stored in the `freq` and `freqsev` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

s <- 2

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(freq = map(lamda, ~rpois(s, .x)),
         freqsev = map(freq, ~map(.x, function(k) rlnorm(k, meanlog, sdlog))))

data2$freq
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 7
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6 0

data2$freqsev
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1]    9330.247   28897.323 2605520.369   20370.283
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1]    645.4047   5206.2183  22461.1778  93729.0634  46892.3129 144595.7492  10110.8606
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1]   2665.955 938950.074
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1]  21931.9763    354.2858 280122.6952   3147.6681
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1]   957.5257 13936.3063  6265.3530  1886.0077  5927.8540  1464.5081
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# numeric(0)
```

#### Update

Here is the way to replace values larger than equal to 500.

```
data3 <- data2 %>%
  mutate(capat500 = map(freqsev, ~map(.x, function(y) ifelse(y >= 500, 500, y))))
```

Comment: This is great @www, thank you very much!
How could I, for example, cap these values at `500`? something like `capat500 <- ifelse(data2$freqsev >= 500, 500, data2$freqsev)`